# Can C# nameof operator reference instance property without instance?

Tags: c#, c#-6.0, nameof

I regularly want to get the name of an instance property of a type, when I have no instance. Currently to do this, I use the following inhouse function which interprets the `Expression[Func[T, object]]` parameter and returns the property name:

```
var str = LinqExtensions.NameOf<ClientService>(x => x.EndDate);
// Now str == "EndDate"
```

However it seems a shame not to use the built in `nameof` operator.

Unfortunately it seems that the `nameof` operator requires either an instance, or, to reference a static properties.

Is there a neat way to use the `nameof` operator instead of our in house function? For example:

```
nameof(ClientService.EndDate) // ClientService.EndDate not normally syntactically valid as EndDate is instance member
```

EDIT

I was completely wrong, the syntax `nameof(ClientService.EndDate)` as described actually works as is.

Comment: Can you post your in-house function? <_<

Answer (score 64, accepted):

In the past, the documentation explicitly explained this, reading in part:

> In the examples you see that **you can use a type name and access an instance method name. You do not need to have an instance of the type**… *[emphasis mine]*

This has been omitted in [the current documentation](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dn986596.aspx). However, the examples still make this clear. Code samples such as `Console.WriteLine(nameof(List<int>.Count));  // output: Count` and `Console.WriteLine(nameof(List<int>.Add));  // output: Add` show how to use `nameof` to obtain the `string` value with the name of an instance member of a class.

I.e. you should be able to write `nameof(ClientService.EndDate)` and have it work, contrary to your observation in the question that this would be *"not normally syntactically valid"*.

If you are having trouble with the syntax, please provide a good [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable code example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) that reliably reproduces whatever error you're getting, and provide the *exact* text of the error message.

Comment: The syntax of `nameof(MyClass.PublicProperty)` is still valid. It evaluates as "PublicProperty". It is not being offered by Intellisense, but writing it manually compiles allright.

Answer (score 4):

Great answer by @Peter Duniho.

In case of name clashes, you can also do the following:

```
ClientService clientservice;
var str = nameof(clientservice.EndDate);
```

Not efficient, but curious enough.

Comment: in the case of name clashes, then both nameofs resolve to the same text, so it may not matter

Comment: @AndrewHill that's a bad idea because half the reason to use `nameof` is so that doing IDE refactors (rename variable) doesn't get missed in literal strings somewhere, by doing a `nameof` on a different class you're reintroducing that chance again.

Comment: I got code inspection notice "Local variable its only used to capture its name"